How were the two streams of Puritan spirituality and Lutheran pietism appropriated into Evangelical spirituality today?
Some form of pietism and Puritanism are definitely identifiable within the spiritual practice of Evangelicals today, whether theologically they identify as Pentecostal, Wesleyan, Reformed, or Lutheran (in reverse order of appearance). Evangelical theologian Donald Bloesch identifies 4 characteristics of Evangelical pietism:

Conversion experience
Bible only for spirituality [typically meditated upon in private or small groups]
Moral earnestness
Social consciousness

Two streams of centuries-earlier spirituality are often cited by scholars as the precursors of the current Evangelical practice, described as a fusion by Baptist scholar Lewis Drummond in his 1980 paper The Puritan-Pietistic Tradition: Its Meaning, History, and Influence in Baptist Life:

Various streams deriving from Pietistic Lutheranism (excluding fringe ones like the Quakers) flowering in German, Switzerland, Scandinavia, and the Baltics, which can be traced to Martin Luther himself (early 16th century).  See Chapter One: Arnold's Protestant Heritage of Peter C. Erb's 1989 book (based on his dissertation) Pietists, Protestants, and mysticism : the use of late Medieval spiritual texts in the work of Gottfried Arnold (1666-1714) for the story of the early origin of Lutheran Pietism.
Puritan spirituality of various ecclesiastical stance (but mostly Reformed) starting in the late 16th century with those who were dissatisfied with insufficient reformation in the Church of England, which then flowered outside England in Netherlands and North America.  (For an intro see the "Puritan Spirituality" section of "Chapter 1: Who were the Puritans" of the 2004 book The Devoted Life: An Invitation to the Puritan Classics edited by Kelly M. Kapic and Randall C. Gleason).

My question is for a short history of how did the 2 types of spirituality from 2 major Protestant theological traditions made their way and got transformed into the characteristic Evangelical spirituality we see in Evangelical churches today.  The answer needs to identify the elements of the practice (such as the 4 above) and show how each element is re-appropriated from the 2 streams into Evangelicalism through a process of theological integration.
